# Como cambiar el estilo del botón de like Facebook y Twitter

Tags: jquery, wordpress, facebook, facebook-api, twitter

Quisiera saber si alguién puede ayudarme.
Quiero cambiar el estilo de los botones de like a una página de facebook y twitter para una página hecha en wordpress, ya intenté con algunos plugins, con el api de facebook pero no logro el resultado, necesito conseguir este diseño
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ya intenté acceder con jquery al contenido del iframe que proporciona Facebook pero no consigo eso tampoco
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aun no intento con twitter pero si pudieran ayudarme u orientarme como hacerlo les agradecería mucho

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta y agrega el código que has intentado.

Comment: Compa, pues creo que es más sencillo que busques el plugin que tenga ese tipo de estilo que buscas, eso hay muchos para wordpress como: Sassy Social Share, porque de otra manera deberás tocar el codigo css detrás del plugin.